# Add class to id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<div class="col-3">
 <a href="#tab-1">
  <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
 <a href="#tab-2">
  <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-2">+</span>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
 <a href="#tab-3">
  <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-3">+</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

I want to change the + to - on clicking each plus symbol.

Here is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/ss2fs5to/9/

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just do this or do I misunderstand your question: http://jsfiddle.net/ss2fs5to/8/ (try clicking the plus signs). What i did was just adding the this statement to the latest line so that the script knows which plus sign is getting clicked.

Comment: It will delete all the content under .col-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `href`'s contain a `#` symbol which needs to be removed if you wish to use this as part of your selector.

You are also trying to use `.data()` incorrectly, `.data()` gets or sets the data attribute; it doesn't select the element. You need to construct your selector as below...

```js
 $('.col-3 a').click(function (e) { // Or bind to any other event you like, or call manually
     e.preventDefault();
     var tabid = ($(this).attr("href")).replace('#',''); // remove #
     $('.plus[data-tab=' + tabid + ']').text("-"); // select by data attribute
 });
```

```css
.col-3 {
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-3"> <a href="#tab-1">
      <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span>
     </a>

</div>
<div class="col-3"> <a href="#tab-2">
      <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-2">+</span>
     </a>

</div>
<div class="col-3"> <a href="#tab-3">
      <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-3">+</span>
     </a>

</div>
```

This would be a much simpler option however...

```js
$('.col-3 a').click(function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('span').text("-");
 });
```

```css
.col-3 {
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-3"> <a href="#tab-1">
      <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span>
     </a>

</div>
<div class="col-3"> <a href="#tab-2">
      <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-2">+</span>
     </a>

</div>
<div class="col-3"> <a href="#tab-3">
      <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-3">+</span>
     </a>

</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant. The second solution worked like charm. Thanks a lot for your help. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this with pure css? For e.g:

```
.col-3 a:hover .plus {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle example link: http://jsfiddle.net/ss2fs5to/10/

Comment: It needs to be on click.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change from "+" to "-" then you can just change text when you click the symbol, like this:

```
 $('.col-3 a').click(function (e) { // Or bind to any other event you like, or call manually

     e.preventDefault();

     $(this).find('span').text('-');

 });
```

Otherwise, if you want to switch from "+" to "-" and viceversa, I suggest this solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-3">
    <a href="#tab-1">
        <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-1"></span>
    </a>
</div>


<div class="col-3">
    <a href="#tab-2">
        <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-2"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
    <a href="#tab-3">
        <span class="plus" data-tab="tab-3"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-3 {
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
}

.plus:after {
    content: "+";
}

.minus:after {
    content: "-";
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.col-3 a').click(function (e) { // Or bind to any other event you like, or call manually

     e.preventDefault();

     $(this).find('span').toggleClass('plus minus');

 });
```

Here's my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8nboo4tq/)